# What is a "receiver" in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, terminology

How is it related to extension functions? Why is `with` [a function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html), not a keyword?

There appears to be no explicit documentation for this topic, only the assumption of knowledge in reference to [extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).

Comment: Existing answers have already told what a receiver is, but it may be helpful to understand where the word comes from: in message-passing object-oriented languages like Smalltalk, method calls are conceived of as messages passed to an object. The object on which the method is called is the "receiver" of the message.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

It is true that there appears to be little existing documentation for the concept of receivers (only a [small side note related to extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver)), which is surprising given:

- their existence springing out of [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html);
- their role in [building a DSL](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html) using said extension functions;
- the existence of a standard library **function** [`with`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html), which given no knowledge of receivers might look like a *keyword*;
- a completely [separate syntax for function types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types).

All these topics have documentation, but nothing goes in-depth on receivers.

---

First:

## What's a receiver?

Any block of code in Kotlin may have a type (or even multiple types) as a **receiver**, making functions and properties of the receiver available in that block of code without qualifying it.

Imagine a block of code like this:

```
{ toLong() }
```

Doesn't make much sense, right? In fact, assigning this to a [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types) of `(Int) -> Long` - where `Int` is the (only) parameter, and the return type is `Long` - would rightfully result in a compilation error. You can fix this by simply qualifying the function call with the implicit single parameter [`it`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter). However, for DSL building, this will cause a bunch of issues:

- Nested blocks of DSL will have their upper layers shadowed:
  `html { it.body { // how to access extensions of html here? } ... }`
  This may not cause issues for a HTML DSL, but may for other use cases.
- It can litter the code with `it` calls, especially for lambdas that use their parameter (soon to be receiver) a lot.

This is where **receivers** come into play.

By assigning this block of code to a function type that has `Int` as a **receiver** (not as a parameter!), the code suddenly compiles:

```
val intToLong: Int.() -> Long = { toLong() }
```

Whats going on here?

---

#### A little side note

This topic assumes familiarity with [function types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types), but a little side note for receivers is needed.

Function types can also have *one* receiver, by prefixing it with the type and a dot. Examples:

```
Int.() -> Long  // taking an integer as receiver producing a long
String.(Long) -> String // taking a string as receiver and long as parameter producing a string
GUI.() -> Unit // taking an GUI and producing nothing
```

Such function types have their parameter list prefixed with the receiver type.

---

## Resolving code with receivers

It is actually incredibly easy to understand how blocks of code with receivers are handled:

**Imagine that, similar to extension functions, the block of code is evaluated inside the class of the receiver type. [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html) effectively becomes amended by the receiver type.**

For our earlier example, `val intToLong: Int.() -> Long = { toLong() }` , it effectively results in the block of code being evaluated in a different context, as if it was placed in a function inside `Int`. Here's a different example using handcrafted types that showcases this better:

```
class Bar

class Foo {
    fun transformToBar(): Bar = TODO()
}

val myBlockOfCodeWithReceiverFoo: (Foo).() -> Bar = { transformToBar() }
```

effectively becomes (in the mind, not code wise - you cannot actually extend classes on the JVM):

```
class Bar 

class Foo {
    fun transformToBar(): Bar = TODO()

    fun myBlockOfCode(): Bar { return transformToBar() }
}

val myBlockOfCodeWithReceiverFoo: (Foo) -> Bar = { it.myBlockOfCode() }
```

Notice how inside of a class, we don't need to use `this` to access `transformToBar` - the same thing happens in a block with a receiver.

It just so happens that the documentation on [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html) also explains how to use an outermost receiver if the current block of code has two receivers, via a [qualified this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified).

---

## Wait, multiple receivers?

Yes. A block of code can have *multiple* receivers, but this currently has no  expression in the type system. The only way to achieve this is via multiple [higher-order functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) that take a single receiver function type. Example:

```
class Foo
class Bar

fun Foo.functionInFoo(): Unit = TODO()
fun Bar.functionInBar(): Unit = TODO()

inline fun higherOrderFunctionTakingFoo(body: (Foo).() -> Unit) = body(Foo())
inline fun higherOrderFunctionTakingBar(body: (Bar).() -> Unit) = body(Bar())

fun example() {
    higherOrderFunctionTakingFoo {
        higherOrderFunctionTakingBar {
            functionInFoo()
            functionInBar()
        }
    }
}
```

Do note that if this feature of the Kotlin language seems inappropriate for your DSL, [@DslMarker](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html#scope-control-dslmarker-since-11) is your friend!

---

## Conclusion

Why does all of this matter? With this knowledge:

- you now understand why you can write `toLong()` in an extension function on a number, instead of having to reference the number somehow. [Maybe your extension function shouldn't be an extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35321347/7079453)
- You can build a DSL for your favorite markup language, maybe help parsing the one or other ([who needs regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7079453)!).
- You understand why [`with`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html), a standard library **function** and not a keyword, exists - the act of amending the scope of a block of code to save on redundant typing is so common, the language designers put it right in the standard library.
- (maybe) you learned a bit about function types on the offshoot.

Comment: Question: I read `(Foo).() -> Unit` as a function that takes a `Foo` as a receiver and no parameter. If that's true, how come you're invoking it with an argument `Foo()`?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Function types with a receiver have their parameter list prefixed with the receiver. This should be in the main body of the post, editing in..

Comment: You can also have multiple receivers when you define extension inside class

Comment: @Panel You raise a valid point, but if somebody comes for this post to understand what a receiver is, the [static/virtual dispatch differences](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members) might be a too high bar...heck, even trips me up sometimes.

Comment: Here is details explanation of different kind of receivers. https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/programmer-dictionary-receiver-b085b1620890

Comment: tl;dr: It's just syntactic sugar so that instead of having to write `{ it: Foo -> it.first(); it.second(); it.etc(); }` you just write `{ first(); second(); etc(); }` and `it` is "magically" inserted.  The first - a conventional lambda - has the notation `(Foo) -> {}`, while the "Magic Lambda" has the notation `Foo.() -> {}` because the parameter's presence is only _implied_.

Answer (score 42):

When you call:

```kotlin
"Hello, World!".length()
```

the string `"Hello, World!"` whose length you're trying to get is called the **receiver**.

---

More generally, any time you write `someObject.someFunction()`, with a `.` between the object and the function name, the object is acting as the receiver for the function. This isn't special to Kotlin, and is common to many programming languages that use objects. So the concept of a receiver is likely very familiar to you, even if you haven't heard the term before.

It's called a receiver because you can think of the function call as sending a request which the object will receive.

Not all functions have a receiver. For example, Kotlin's `println()` function is a top-level function. When you write:

```kotlin
println("Hello, World!")
```

you don't have to put any object (or `.`) before the function call. There's no receiver because the `println()` function doesn't live inside an object.

## On the receiving end

Now let's look at what a function call looks like from the point of view of the receiver itself. Imagine we've written a class that displays a simple greeting message:

```kotlin
class Greeter(val name: String) {
    fun displayGreeting() {
        println("Hello, ${this.name}!")
    }
}
```

To call `displayGreeting()`, we first create an instance of `Greeter`, then we can use that object as a receiver to call the function:

```kotlin
val aliceGreeter = Greeter("Alice")
val bobGreeter = Greeter("Bob")
aliceGreeter.displayGreeting() // prints "Hello, Alice!"
bobGreeter.displayGreeting() // prints "Hello, Bob!"
```

How does the `displayGreeting` function know which name to display each time? The answer is the keyword `this`, which always refers to the **current receiver**.

- When we call `aliceGreeter.displayGreeting()`, the receiver is `aliceGreeter`, so `this.name` points to `"Alice"`.
- When we call `bobGreeter.displayGreeting()`, the receiver is `bobGreeter`, so `this.name` points to `"Bob"`.

## Implicit receivers

Most of the time, there's actually no need to write `this`. We can replace `this.name` with just `name` and it will implicitly point to the `name` property of the current receiver.

```kotlin
class Greeter(val name: String) {
    fun displayGreeting() {
        println("Hello, $name!")
    }
}
```

Notice how that differs from accessing a property from outside the class. To print the name from outside, we'd have to write out the full name of the receiver:

```kotlin
println("Hello, ${aliceGreeter.name}")
```

By writing the function inside the class, we can omit the receiver completely, making the whole thing much shorter. The call to `name` still has a receiver, we just didn't have to write it out. We can say that we accessed the `name` property using an **implicit receiver**.

Member functions of a class often need to access many other functions and properties of their own class, so implicit receivers are very useful. They shorten the code and can make it easier to read and write.

## How do receivers relate to extensions?

So far, it seems like a receiver is doing two things for us:

1. Sending a function call to a specific object, because the function lives inside that object
2. Allowing a function convenient and concise access to the other properties and functions that live inside the same object

What if we want to write a function that can use an implicit receiver for convenient access to the properties and functions of an object, but we don't want to (or can't) write our new function inside that object/class? This is where Kotlin's extension functions come in.

```kotlin
fun Greeter.displayAnotherGreeting() {
    println("Hello again, $name!")
}
```

This function doesn't live inside `Greeter`, but it accesses `Greeter` *as if it was a receiver*. Notice the receiver type before the function name, which tells us that this is an extension function. In the body of the extension function, we can once again access `name` without its receiver, even though we're not actually inside the `Greeter` class.

You could say that this isn't a "real" receiver, because we're not actually sending the function call to an object. The function lives outside the object. We're just using the syntax and appearance of a receiver because it makes for convenient and concise code. We can call this an **extension receiver**, to distinguish it from the **dispatch receiver** that exists for functions that are really inside an object.

Extension functions are called in the same way as member functions, with a receiver object before the function name.

```kotlin
val aliceGreeter = Greeter("Alice")
aliceGreeter.displayAnotherGreeting() // prints "Hello again, Alice!"
```

Because the function is always called with an object in the receiver position before the function name, it can access that object using the keyword `this`. Like a member function, an extension function can also leave out `this` and access the receiver's other properties and functions using the current receiver instance as the implicit receiver.

**One of the main reasons extension functions are useful is that the current extension receiver instance can be used as an implicit receiver inside the body of the function.**

## What does `with` do?

So far we've seen two ways to make something available as an implicit receiver:

1. Create a function inside the receiver class
2. Create an extension function outside the class

Both approaches require creating a function. Can we have the convenience of an implicit receiver without declaring a new function at all?

The answer is to call `with`:

```kotlin
with(aliceGreeter) {
    println("Hello again, $name!")
}
```

Inside the block body of the call to `with(aliceGreeter) { ... }`, `aliceGreeter` is available as an **implicit receiver** and we can once again access `name` without its receiver.

So how come `with` can be implemented as a function, rather than a language feature? How is it possible to simply take an object and magic it into an implicit receiver?

The answer lies with lambda functions. Let's consider our `displayAnotherGreeting` extension function again. We declared it as a function, but we could instead write it as a lambda:

```kotlin
val displayAnotherGreeting: Greeter.() -> Unit = { 
    println("Hello again, $name!")
}
```

We can still call `aliceGreeter.displayAnotherGreeting()` the same as before, and the code inside the function is the same, complete with implicit receiver. Our extension function has become a **lambda with receiver**. Note the way the `Greeter.() -> Unit` function type is written, with the extension receiver `Greeter` listed before the (empty) parameter list `()`.

Now, watch what happens when we pass this lambda function as an argument to another function:

```kotlin
fun runLambda(greeter: Greeter, lambda: Greeter.() -> Unit) {
   greeter.lambda()
}
```

The first argument is the object that we want to use as the receiver. The second argument is the lambda function we want to run. All `runLambda` does is to call the provided lambda parameter, using the `greeter` parameter as the lambda's receiver.

Substituting the code from our `displayAnotherGreeting` lambda function into the second argument, we can call `runLambda` like this:

```
runLambda(aliceGreeter) {
    println("Hello again, $name!")
}
```

And just like that, we've turned `aliceGreeter` into an implicit receiver. Kotlin's `with` function is simply a generic version of this that works with any type.

## Recap

- When you call `someObject.someFunction()`, `someObject` is acting as the **receiver** that receives the function call
- Inside `someFunction`, `someObject` is "in scope" as the current receiver instance, and can be accessed as `this`
- When a receiver is in scope, you can leave out the word `this` and access its properties and functions using an **implicit receiver**
- Extension functions let you benefit from the receiver syntax and implicit receivers without actually dispatching a function call to an object
- Kotlin's `with` function uses a **lambda with receiver** to make receivers available anywhere, not just inside member functions and extension functions

Comment: great explanation; thank you very very much @Sam to take the time to write it for all of us

Comment: This is such an important point that is easily missed in the explanation: "It's called a receiver because you can think of the function call as sending a request which the object will receive." If I were creating the terminology, I would never call it a receiver. It is totally unintuitive to what is going on - for me, at least.

Comment: "with the extension receiver Greeter listed before the (empty) parameter list ()" is also a mind bending concept worthy of attention. Greeter as an extension is obvious, but considering it also as a receiver opens it up to a new way to look at what it brings to the party.

Answer (score 19):

Kotlin knows the concept of a *function literals with receiver*. It enables access on visible methods and properties of a **receiver** of a lambda within its body without having to use any additional qualifier. That's very similar to extension functions in which you can as well access members of the receiver object inside the extension.

A simple example, also one of the greatest functions in the Kotlin standard library, is `apply`:

```
public inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T { 
    block()
    return this 
}
```

Here, `block` is a function literal with receiver. This block parameter is executed by the function and the receiver of apply, `T`, is returned to the caller. In action this looks as follows:

```
val foo: Bar = Bar().apply {
    color = RED
    text = "Foo"
}
```

We instantiate an object of `Bar` and call `apply` on it. The instance of `Bar` becomes the receiver of `apply`. The `block`, passed as an argument in curly brackets does not need to use additional qualifiers to access and modify the properties `color` and `text`.

The concept of lambdas with receiver is also the most important feature for writing DSLs with Kotlin.

Comment: As this may be the first time you see this syntax, the `{...}` in `apply{...}` is just the lambda function as argument to `apply`. The lambda is a *trailing lambda*, where it doesn't have to be in the apply parentheses. It could actually be apply({...}), which would be less confusing for me when first learning this. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter

Answer (score 17):

```
var greet: String.() -> Unit = { println("Hello $this") }
```

this defines a variable of *type* `String.() -> Unit`, which tells you

- **`String`** is the **receiver**
- `() -> Unit` is the function type

Like [F. George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7079453/f-george) mentioned above, all methods of this receiver can be called in the method body.

So, in our example, `this` is used to print the `String`. The function can be invoked by writing...

```
greet("Fitzgerald") // result is "Hello Fitzgerald"
```

<sub>the above code snippet was taken from [Kotlin Function Literals with Receiver – Quick Introduction](https://blog.simon-wirtz.de/function-literals-with-receiver-quick-introduction/) by Simon Wirtz.</sub>

Comment: In this case we can make different type of calls: greet("my text") which has the same effect with "my text".greet()

Comment: I don't get it. `greet` is defined as a method that has a `String` receiver but no parameters. So I understand how we can call `"Fitzgerald".greet()`, but how can we call `greet("Fitzgerald")`?

Comment: (FYI the link to the Simon Wirtz article is broken.)

Answer (score 13):

Simply put ( without any extra words or complications) , the "Receiver" is the type being extended in the extension function or the class name.  Using the examples given in answers above

```
 fun Foo.functionInFoo(): Unit = TODO()
```

Type "Foo" is the "Receiver"

```
 var greet: String.() -> Unit = { println("Hello $this") }
```

Type "String" is the "Receiver"

Additional tip: Look out for the Class before the fullstop(.) in the "fun" (function) declaration

```
fun receiver_class.function_name() {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply put:

- the **receiver type** is the type an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) extends
- the **receiver object** is the object an extension function is called on; the `this` keyword inside the function body corresponds to the receiver object

An extension function example:

```kotlin
// `Int` is the receiver type
// `this` is the receiver object
fun Int.squareDouble() = toLong() * this

// a receiver object `8` of type `Int` is passed to the `square` function
val result = 8.square()
```

A [function literal](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver) example, which is pretty much the same:

```kotlin
// `Int` is the receiver type
// `this` is the receiver object
val square: Int.() -> Long = { toLong() * this }

// a receiver object `8` of type `Int` is passed to the `square` function
val result1 = 8.square()
val result2 = square(8) // this call is equal to the previous one
```

Answer (score 2):

The object instance before the . is the receiver. This is in essence the "Scope" you will define this lambda within. This is all you need to know, really, because the functions and properties(varibles, companions e.t.c) you will be using in the lambda will be those provided within this scope.

```
        class Music(){
    
        var track:String=""
    
        fun printTrack():Unit{
            println(track)
        }
    }
    
    //Music class is the receiver of this function, in other words, the lambda can be piled after a Music class just like its extension function Since Music is an instance, refer to it by 'this', refer to lambda parameters by 'it', like always
    val track_name:Music.(String)->Unit={track=it;printTrack()}
/*Create an Instance of Music and immediately call its function received by the name 'track_name', and exclusively available to instances of this class*/
Music().track_name("Still Breathing")

//Output
Still Breathing
```

You define this variable with and all the parameters and return types it will have but among all the constructs defined, only the object instance can call the var, just like it would an extension function and supply to it its constructs, hence "receiving" it.
A receiver would hence be loosely defined as an object for which an extension function is defined using the idiomatic style of lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

Typically in Java or Kotlin you have methods or functions with input parameters of type T. In Kotlin you can also have extension functions that receive a value of type T.

If you have a function that accepts a String parameter for example:

```
fun hasWhitespace(line: String): Boolean {
    for (ch in line) if (ch.isWhitespace()) return true
    return false
}
```

converting the parameter to a receiver (which you can do automatically with IntelliJ):

```
fun String.hasWhitespace(): Boolean {
    for (ch in this) if (ch.isWhitespace()) return true
    return false
}
```

we now have an extension function that receives a String and we can access the value with `this`