# When should I use let {} and when just plain != null

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

How would you write the following code in a more kotlinic way ?

```
var returnValue = ...
val s3data = presignedUrl.body()
if (s3data != null) {
    val uploadImage = api.uploadImage(s3data.bucketUrl, s3data.awsAccessKeyId, s3data.policy, s3data.key, s3data.signature, body).execute()
    if (!uploadImage.isSuccessful) {
        crashReporterService.sendIssue("Failed uploading file", "Failed uploading file ${uploadImage.raw()}")
        returnValue = Result.FAILURE
    } else {
        returnValue = Result.SUCCESS
    }
} else {
    crashReporterService.sendIssue("Failed uploading image", "Error - ${presignedUrl.raw()}")
    returnValue = Result.FAILURE
}

return returnValue
```

I can use let, but I feel it makes the code more complicated to understand

Comment: a note on your code: returning asap is a good practice afaik, reduces scope and simplifies the logic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Common shared code - in this case, error reporting and return with failure result - can be consolidated into a [local function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#local-functions).
- Nullability causing a return (in this case, `s3data` being nullable) can usually be replaced with a returning [?: elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator).
- When typing the same variable over and over again (in this case, accessing `s3data`), a [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) block is appropriate. If confused, see [What is a "receiver" in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45875491/7079453)
- As already stated in another answer, if/else blocks are an expression in Kotlin.

I would therefore find the following implementation most ideomatic, subject to proper naming of parameters for the local function:

```
fun foo() {
    fun failure(p0: String, p1: String) = crashReporterService.sendIssue(p0, p1).let { Result.FAILURE }
    val s3data = presignedUrl.body() ?: return failure("Failed uploading image", "Error - ${presignedUrl.raw()}")
    val uploadImage = s3data.run { api.uploadImage(bucketUrl, awsAccessKeyId, policy, key, signature, body).execute() }

    return if (uploadImage.isSuccessful) {
        Result.SUCCESS
    } else {
        failure("Failed uploading file", "Failed uploading file ${uploadImage.raw()}")
    }
}
```

Your question is bordering on code review, so you'll probably also be happy to know there's a [dedicated Stack Exchange network just for that.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Do read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/145613) before, however.

Answer (score 4):

[`if`/`else` is an expression in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#if-expression), so the following is certainly more Kotlinesque:

```
val s3data = presignedUrl.body()
return if (s3data != null) {
    val uploadImage = api.uploadImage(s3data.bucketUrl, s3data.awsAccessKeyId, s3data.policy, s3data.key, s3data.signature, body).execute()
    if (!uploadImage.isSuccessful) {
        crashReporterService.sendIssue("Failed uploading file", "Failed uploading file ${uploadImage.raw()}")
        Result.FAILURE
    } else {
        Result.SUCCESS
    }
} else {
    crashReporterService.sendIssue("Failed uploading image", "Error - ${presignedUrl.raw()}")
    Result.FAILURE
}
```