# Kotlin: difference between IT and THIS keyword

Tags: android, kotlin

In one of the kotlin interviews, someone asked me the difference between `it` & `this` keywords.

I have a search on google but unable to find a proper answer for the question.

Can someone guide me what's the actual difference between these two?

I know this is very basic question, I am a novice in the kotlin.

Answer (score 21):

`it` is only relevant inside a lambda with a single parameter. It is the default name for a single parameter and is a shorthand that allows you to omit naming the single parameter.  A function that is declared this way might look like this:

```
(String) -> Unit
```

In a lambda, `this` is the receiver argument. It only works if the function is defined as having a receiver, like this:

```
String.() -> Unit
```

If the function declaration does not have a receiver, `this` has the same meaning it does outside the scope of the lambda. For an extension function, that’s the receiver of the extension function. Otherwise, it’s the class containing the function.

Comment: Huh? You write about 'it' and 'this' but provide no examples using them. And what is "unit"?

Answer (score 18):

You need to know about [Scope Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html):

> The Kotlin standard library contains several functions whose sole
> purpose is to execute a block of code within the context of an object.
> When you call such a function on an object with a lambda expression
> provided, it forms a temporary scope.

Inside this scope there is a [Context](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#context-object-this-or-it) object either as `this` or `it`

In Scope functions `run`, `apply` and `with` the scope is (temporarily) changed to the scope of the object you are calling this function on:

```
val str = "Hello"
str.run {
    //Here this refers to str
}
```

In Scope functions `let`, `also` the scope is not changed (remains the same as caller scope) but your lambda will receive the context as `it` inside the lambda:

```
val str = "Hello"
str.let {
    //Here it refers to str
}
```

You can check the links for more information.

Comment: thank you for the details information. but Why can't we use "IT" in the extension functions? we need to use "THIS" inside extension function.

Comment: @HarshShah Because extension functions have a receiver type. You can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45875492/2757664

Comment: Can you write codes that shows the difference of use? because I don't understand why you put code examples that are practically the same.

Comment: @SalimMazariBoufares The difference of the ```this``` and ```it``` keyword are basically this (which was asked in the question). There is a small difference between each scope function though, and it totally depends on your use case. I would suggest reading this link: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#function-selection

Comment: @SaeedEntezari Well, thank you for the answer, but that was not my question, you literally put two similar codes as to show some kind of difference, but at this point there is no difference in use between run and let. A minimal example could be:
    val str = "Hello";
    str.let {
        it.length
    };

    str.run {
        length
    }

Comment: @Saeed afarin saeed jan

Answer (score 7):

Difference between **it** & **this** keywords can be explained by taking example of lambda method receivers *(a.k.a higher order functions)*.

Let's say you've written a function or using a function which provides you callback as lambda method receiver. Something like this: **`() -> Unit`**

So, there are two possibilities how you want your callback to be:

1. **Providing parameter to callback**

   - Parameter by callback means you want to give your callback a parameter that caller can use on the time of invocation, also considered as **it**.

Whatever written above simply means: **`(Int) -> Unit`**. this functional method parameter can give you integer at the time of invocation.

Check out the snippet below:

```
fun someMethodWithCallback(callback: (Int) -> Unit) {
    callback(0)
}

// On the time of consumption, the `Int` parameter by default exposed to callback as it parameter.
obj.someMethodWithCallback { it -> // Here it is the method parameter of callback that we passed, you can also rename it to any other named value
    // it can be directly used as Int value if needed or you can rename it at receiver above
}
```

*Note: You can provide multiple parameters to callback and then you won't be able to receive **it**, rather callback would provide you number of variables passed instead.*

2. **Providing object to callback**

   - Another way to provide callback is by providing object itself as callback parameter. Which means that callback syntax slightly changes and gives you object itself as callback parameter **this**.

Whatever written above simply means: **`Int.() -> Unit`**. this functional method object can give you integer at the time of invocation.

Check out the snippet below:

```
fun someMethodWithCallback(callback: Int.() -> Unit) {
    callback(0)
}

// On the time of consumption, the `Int` parameter by default exposed to callback as it parameter.
obj.someMethodWithCallback { this // Here this is the method object of callback that we passed, you can not rename it to anything else
    // it can be used as Int value by referencing as this
}
```

Hope it make sense!

Comment: thank you for the details information. but Why can't we use "IT" in the extension functions? we need to use "THIS" inside extension function.

Answer (score 2):

If this helps some one :

With scope like : run, apply, with, to call the methods of the object, we can call them directly as it has scope of the object. In another words run-block has "this" scope.

```
private fun methodWithRun() {

    val dummy = Dummy()
    dummy.run {
        this.dummyFun()
        this.dummyVar = "10"
    }
    
}
```

While scope like : let, also, to call the methods of the object, we can call them using the "it" as it has scope of the class win which this method is written.

```
private fun methodWithLet() {
    
    val dummy = Dummy()
    dummy.let {
        it.dummyFun()
        it.dummyVar = "10";
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at kotlin scope functions doc:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html

Some of them have "**this**" in their scopes and others use "**it**".
The difference is the following:

**this:** When you use scope functions that use "**this**", f.i. **apply {}** it changes the context of function's scope to the context of an object on which this function was called, e.g.:

```
//Outer context in outer scope

val alice = Person("Alice").apply {

//Person object's context in function's inner scope

this.age = 20   //"this" refers to the object's context 
city = "London" //you can skip writing "this" because you are in the context of object
}
```

**it**: When you use functions that use "**it**", f.i. **also {}** it DOES NOT change the context of function's scope, so it remains the same as the context where the function was called, e.g.:

```
//Outer context in outer scope

val alice = Person("Alice").also {

//Same outer context in function's inner scope

it.age = 20        //"it" refers to the object's reference holder e.g. alice
it.city = "London" //you can not skip writing "it" because you are in outer context
}
```

**NOTE:**
The context and the scope are 2 different things.
In both cases the scope is changed so that if you declare a local variable within that scope it will not be visible from outer scope, and in 1 case the context changes and in the other one it remains the same and hence the usage of "this" and "it".

Answer (score 1):

I would like to go extreme fundamental with no fancy words.
 
**it keyword** 
 When you have one parameter you can call using **it**
keyword and it works so good with HOF, for instance,

```
 private fun itKeyword(itKeyword:(String) -> Unit) {
        itKeyword("")
    }

    fun callItFun() {
        itKeyword {//it:String // this is high light over here like this

        }
```

But if you try to do something like this:

```
private fun itKeyword(itKeyword:(String, Int) -> Unit) {
        itKeyword("", 1)
    }

    fun callItFun() {
        itKeyword {yourName, age -> //yourName, age is define by user
        }
   }
```

see? there is no **it** keyword define over here by compiler but instead we have to pass two parameters when we defined HOF but if we keep this empty, compiler will give us error *Hey pass something dude, i don't what variable you are talking about there are two variables passed over here.*
That means, when you have only one parameter you can call it by using *it* keyword.
**this keyword**
there are two scope or variables/properties global and local scope, when you have defined some variable as a global scope and you wanna call it in multiple methods/functions and at some place you have to use same type of  another variable with the same name at local scope, in that case we will be using this keyword and why is that so?

```
private lateinit var mContext: Context

    fun thisKeyword(mContext: Context) {
        this.mContext = mContext
    }
```

but what if we don't use *this* keyword and keep it like this:

```
private lateinit var mContext: Context
    fun thisKeyword(mContext: Context) {
        mContext = mContext
    }
```

Compiler would say, *mah man what have you done, didn't ring a bell in my head* JK, Compiler would say, *Val cannot be reassigned*, wait what? we didn't init it as a val but if we see at global scope we have init it as var but guess what? compile is right. In Kotlin **when pass something into functions parameter they act as a Val by default** which means without *this* compiler was using local scope variables not global scope but when we use *this* keyword we tell compiler, with keyword this property over here before = is global scope **this.mContext** and after = is local one so this is the reason we use **this** keyword to refrains from variable conflict.
 i hope this helps, thankYou().