# extension lambdas accept wrong parameters

Tags: function, kotlin

I think an extension lambda requires that you pass in the correct argument, but i seems not to do so in the following example.

```
 

        open class Base {
        open fun f() = 1
    }
    class Derived : Base() {
        override fun f() = 99
    }
    fun Base.g(): Int { return f()}
    fun Base.h(xl: Base.() -> Int): Int { return xl()}
    
    fun main() {
        val b: Base = Derived() // Upcast
        println(b.g())
        println(b.h { f()}) // [1]
}
```

I understand that Base.h takes a function that takes a Base object as its parameter. But line [1] shows that it accepts f(), which is a function that takes no parameter. I was thinking hard about this and I prefixed it with this.f() and it still worked. Not convinced, I modified the code as follows:

```
    open class Base {
        open fun f() = 1
    }
    class Derived : Base() {
        override fun f() = 99
    }
    fun Base.g(): Int { return f()}
    fun Base.h(xl: (Base) -> Int): Int { return xl(Base())}
    fun test(i:Int) = 1
    fun main() {
        val b: Base = Derived() // Upcast
        println(b.g())
        println(b.h { test(1) })
    }
```

This code works. I've run it to verify. And as you can see, b.h() accepts test(), which takes an Int. And this is contrary to the fact that Base.h() takes a Base.

Could you explain this? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Note the curly brackets around the functions that are passed in!*** They change everything.

In the second code, `b.h { test(1) }` is *not* passing the function `test` to `b.h`. The syntax to pass `test` to `b.h` would be `b.h(::test)`, and *that* does produce an error as you would expect.

`b.h { test(1) }` passes a function (a [lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions)) that takes a `Base` as parameter, ignores that parameter, calls `test(1)` and returns the result. You are basically passing a function that looks like this to `b.h`:

```
fun foo(p: Base) = test(1)
```

You might be wondering how Kotlin knows about `Base` when you did not write the word `Base` in the call at all. Well, it can just look at the declaration of `b.h`, and see that `{ test(1) }` must take a parameter of `Base`.

The first code snippet is a bit different, because `b.h` accepts a `Base.() -> Int` in that case. `Base.() -> Int` represents a function whose [*receiver type*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875491/what-is-a-receiver-in-kotlin) is `Base`, that is, a function `func` that can be called like `someBaseObject.func()`. Compare this to a function `func` that takes a `Base` object as parameter, which can be called like `func(someBaseObject)`.

Again, `{ f() }` is not passing the function `f`. It is a lambda expression that does nothing but calls `f`. In this case though, `f` itself can be passed to `b.h` (`b.h(Base::f)`), because it *is* a function with a receiver type of `Base`! You *can* do `someBaseObject.f()`, can't you? Passing the lambda is similar to passing an extension function that is declared like this (you're just "wrapping" `f` in another function):

```
fun Base.foo() = f()
```

And since the receiver of the function is `Base`, you are able to access other functions that has `Base` as the receiver (such as `f`) in the lambda. You can also specify the receiver (which is `this`) explicitly.