# How does defining functions within functions work?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I am trying to get to know Kotlin through making a Ktor program, and was following the documentation when I noticed this:

```
fun Application.configureRouting() {

    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("Hello World!")
        }
    }
}
```

How does the `routing {}` and `get("/") {}` work? What does it mean? Is routing and get a function being overridden within the `Application.configureRouting()` function?

Comment: This is called DSL or type safe builder: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-safe-builders.html#how-it-works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you confused **Kotlin's [type-safe builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-safe-builders.html)** with **[local functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#local-functions)**. It's possible to define a function inside another function *(local function)* which limits the scope in which we can access the child function.

Here's an example of a *local function*:

```kotlin
fun foo() {
    fun bar() {
        println("I'm within a local function.")
    }

    println("We can call bar only from foo.")
    bar()
}
```

---

##### In case of **type-safe builders** ***(the `routing` function of your code)***, a part of the syntax that enabled this look and feel, is:

> According to Kotlin convention, if the last parameter of a function is a function, then a lambda expression passed as the corresponding argument can be placed **outside the parentheses**.

When the only parameter of a function is of a lambda type, the parentheses can be **omitted**. Also, adding [a receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875491/what-is-a-receiver-in-kotlin) to a single lambda parameter will result in a behavior similar to the `routing` function that you mentioned. If my explanation is not sufficient, you can read more about type-safe builders [from the official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-safe-builders.html).