# What happens when using 'this' inside a lambda expression that is sent to let function?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, let

I've looked at the source code of *let* function:

```
    @kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    return block(this)
}
```

i clearly understand that using **it** keyword inside of the block (code) i'm sending to
let function will refer to the object that called the **let** function.
But on which object does **this** keyword will refer if i will use it inside the block (code).
The way i see it, it should be the same object that **it** refer to, but i'm not sure.
My computer gone bad so i can't test it by myself.
Can someone not only give me the answer but also will explain me the logic behind the **this** keyword in the situation above?

example of code:

```
val p:Preson = Person()
p.let{**this**}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in the `let` lambda (block) means the same thing as it does outside the `let` lambda. The `let` lambda does not suddenly "change" what `this` means.

For example:

```
class Foo {
    fun foo() {
        // here, "this" refers to the receiver of foo(), i.e. some instance of Foo
        1.let {
            // here, "it" refers to 1, 
            // and "this" refers to the receiver of foo() too
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    // here, "this" does not mean anything, main() has no receiver
    2.let {
        // here, "it" refers to 2, 
        // and "this" does not mean anything either
    }
}
```

This is because `this` refers to the [receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875491/what-is-a-receiver-in-kotlin) of a function, but the function type of the parameter that `let` takes has no receiver:

```
public inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R {
                                      ^^^^^^^^
```

Compare that to `run`, which is very similar to `let`, except its receiver as the receiver of the `block` parameter:

```
public inline fun <T, R> T.run(block: T.() -> R): R {
    return this.block() // instead of block(this) like let
}
```

which means that:

```
1.let {
    // here, "this" refers to 1
    // "it" does not mean anything because the function type T.() -> R has no parameters
}
```

Another example that uses both `this` and `it`:

```
fun usesBoth(x: Int, y: String, block: Int.(String) -> Unit) {
    x.block(y)
}
```

If you call `usesBoth` with a lambda,

```
usesBoth(1, "x") {
    println(this) // prints 1
    println(it)   // prints x
}
```

`this` in the lambda would refer to 1, because `block` is called on `x` in `usesBoth`, and `it` would refer to "x", because `y` is passed to `block` as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks but i didn't understand the example with usesBoth...
Maybe writing something inside {...} may help me?

Comment: @Eitanos30 See the edits. Does that help?

Comment: thanks a lot. Your answer and patience is awesome. But i have to accept the answer of the broot since he was the first to answer. Thanks a lot and sorry!

Comment: @Eitanos30 Well, you don't have to accept the first answer :-) Accept what you think is the most useful / easy to understand. Some people in the future could find your question, having similar concerns and most probably they will read the accepted answer first.

Comment: You both have helped me a lotttttt and both answers are great. Hard life :)

Answer (score 1):

`this` is just one of parameters (called a "receiver") that could be passed to the lambda by a calling code. If lambda doesn't support a receiver, as in the `let` example, `this` will be just `this` of the enclosing code:

```kotlin
class Foo {
    fun foo() {
        val p = Person()
        p.let{ this } // `this` is `Foo`
    }
}
```

If lambda has a receiver then it depends what will be passed to it as `this`. For example, a very similar function to `let`, but passing the object as `this` is `apply`:

```kotlin
class Foo {
    fun foo() {
        val p = Person()
        p.apply{ this } // `this` is `Person`
    }
}
```

Of course, `this` doesn't have to be the object that we invoked the function on. It could be just any object, it depends on what the function will pass to the lambda. For example, in Kotlin stdlib we have a `buildString()` function that instantiates a `StringBuilder`, runs the lambda passing the `StringBuilder` as `this` and then returns a string that was built by the lambda. We use this function like this:

```kotlin
val s = buildString {
    // `this` is `StringBuilder`
    append("hello") // implicit this.append()
    append("world")
}
```

By looking into `buildString()` signature we can see that the lambda receives `StringBuilder` as its receiver:

```kotlin
public inline fun buildString(builderAction: StringBuilder.() -> Unit): String {
```

You can read more about lambdas with receivers in the documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html

Comment: thanks. can you explain me the example with buildString? I didn't get it

Comment: @Eitanos30 I updated my answer adding more info about `buildString()`.

Comment: you explanation was great. And it very help me to understand. But for the others readers in the future i think they will prefer the second answer.
Thanks a lot for you wonderful help and sorry for the inconvenience