# "this expression" in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, this

I know the meaning of "this expression" in almost language. But below code in Kotlin make total confuse:

```
fun <A, B, C> (A.(B) -> C).swap(): (B.(A) -> C) = { a: A -> // 1
    a.this@swap(this)
}
```

the interpret phrase for the function definition is that: "`swap` as a function that converts a function of type `A.(B)->C` in a function
of type `B.(A)->C` , basically swapping the receivers of types `A` and `B`.

`a.this` is something i can not get. If just `this` in that place, i will understand the scope are belong to (A.(B) -> C).

`a.this@swap` is a monster now, and `a.this@swap(this)` is the brain explode.

is that true if i think `a.this` is "outside" of `a`, but if that is, i also do not get what it is. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as written is indeed very confusing and unreadable. To understand it, let's start with a function that turns a `(A, B) -> C` to a `(B, A) -> C`:

```
fun <A, B, C> swap(f: (A, B) -> C): (B, A) -> C = { b, a ->
    f(a, b)
}
```

Hopefully this is straightforward enough to not need any explanation.

Instead of `(A, B) -> C` and `(B, A) -> C`, let's change this function to work with `A.(B) -> C` and `B.(A) -> C`. These function types have a [receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45875491/5133585). `B.(A) -> C` still takes two parameters `B` and `A`, but `B` is the *receiver*. This means that it is referred to as `this` inside a function of that type.

So in the lambda, we remove the first parameter `b` (that's the receiver now), and refer to it using `this`.

```
fun <A, B, C> swap(f: A.(B) -> C): B.(A) -> C = { a ->
    // here, "this" refers to the receiver of the returned function, of type B
    f(a, this)
}
```

Note that since `f` has `A` as the receiver, `f(a, this)` can be alternatively written as `a.f(this)`. Let's do that instead:

```
fun <A, B, C> swap(f: A.(B) -> C): B.(A) -> C = { a ->
    // same as f(a, this)
    a.f(this)
}
```

The functions we have written so far all take a parameter `f`. What if we made this parameter the *receiver* of `swap`? In other words, we write `swap` as an extension function of `A.(B) -> C`.

Think about how you would refer to the receiver of `swap` inside the lambda you return. `this` inside the lambda would refer to the receiver of the returned `B.(A) -> C`, since that's the "closest" receiver. You would need to use a [qualified](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/this-expressions.html#qualified-this) `this` - `this@swap`.

So we can replace `f` with `this@swap`, and we reach the code in the question:

```
fun <A, B, C> (A.(B) -> C).swap(): B.(A) -> C = { a ->
    // this@swap refers to the receiver of swap
    // this refers to the receiver of the returned lambda i.e. an instance of B
    a.this@swap(this)
}
```

IMO, `this@swap(a, this)` is more readable.

Comment: `(A, B) -> C` easy to understand. `(A) -> (B) -> C` is harder, but we see often. But `(A.(B) -> C)` is weir (for me). How we interpret that? Example, in version `(A, B) ->C`, function take  2 parameters, the first type `A`, the second type `B` and return the result of type `C`. In version of High Order Function `(A) -> (B) -> C`, it mean a function take 1 parameter of type `A` and return a function which take 1 parameter of type `B` and return value of type `C`. But with `A.(B) -> C`, i never see anything like that. Is that an innovation of Kotlin? Some Haskell book i'd read, there wasn't.

Comment: @tutu `A.(B) -> C` is basically `(A, B) -> C`, except 1) Instead of doing `f(a, b)`, you can also do `a.f(b)`, and 2) you use `this` to refer to the `A` parameter. I'm not sure if this is an innovation of Kotlin, but none of the other languages I know have this feature. For more info, see the question about receivers I linked.

Comment: in the case. `a.f(b)`, it become easier to get that `this` refer to the `A` parameter (the receiver). But is there a name for A.(B) (what its type - in my opinion, it look like closure ). In the case (A) -> (B) ->C, we call that Currying. If i must call, the A.(B) -> C become: the function take a member of  object type A which have type B as parameter, and return result of type C - or - the function take parameter of type B which have a receiver of type A (which `this` refer to) and return result of type C?

Comment: @tutu `A.(B)` is not a type, in the same way that `A ->` is not a type. The [Kotlin spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-system.html#function-types) calls `A.(B) -> C` a "function type with receiver". A "function that takes a parameter of type B and a receiver of type A and return type of C" like you said, would be understandable too.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about `a.this`, but the function body is not using `a.this` at all. In fact you should be parsing the function body by thinking of `this@swap` as an individual instance.

Inside the definition of `swap`:

- `this` is the receiver in the lambda (an instance of type B), which is not what you want.
- `this@swap` is the receiver of the function `swap`. This receiver is an instance of another function.

Consider a typical usage:

```
val add: String.(String) -> String = { this + it }
"a".add("b")   // gives "ab"
val addTo = add.swap()
"a".addTo("b") // gives "ba"
```

The swap function transforms the `add` function by swapping its receiver with its argument.

Comment: (Sweeper's answer gives valuable detail and background, but I think the first paragraph of this answer gets right to the heart of the question — and is just what I would have posted!)

Comment: yes, it complete Sweeper's answer.